# Qt selection handles on desktop using PySide?

Tags: qt, pyside, qtextedit, textselection

I would like to add selection handles to a QTextEdit widget so that after the user selects text he or she can expand or shrink the selection in either direction. I understand support for this functionality has been formally added to Qt, [but I only see Android mentioned](https://appbus.wordpress.com/2017/03/25/text-selection-handles-qt-5-8/). Is it available for desktop? Is it accessible from PySide? I'm guessing it is too recent for PySide to have the appropriate wrapper.

If selection handles are not formally available, I can imagine how to override the keyPressEvent so that CTRL-click expands or shrinks the current selection by jumping to the cursor's location. However, instead, I would prefer to have a visual cue that can be selected and dragged with a regular mouse-click. Are there graphical widgets that can be painted on top of a QTextEdit window and modified to behave like selection handles?

Comment: Are you using qml or the qwidgets?

Comment: The nearest equivalent would be [QRubberBand](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qrubberband.html).

Comment: Note that the selection can already be extended (from the current caret position) with shift+click. So all you really need is a way to move the caret from one end of the selection to the other (so it can be extended in both directions). There's also ctrl+shift+right/left to select the next/previous word, and shift+home/end to select the start/end of the line.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I'm using qwidgets.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thank you. I was unaware of the shift+click functionality. I see what you mean about currently only being able to extend the selection in one direction. Is "the caret" a formal object or just the name of the place where the selection was initially anchored? I will look at the QRubberBand too.

Comment: @davideps. The caret is the blinking vertical line that is used to indicate the current insertion point. If you select downwards, it will be at the bottom of the selection; select upwards and it will be at the top. The selection anchor is at the opposite end to the caret (so it's where the selection started from). I suppose you could just change the existing shift+click behaviour so it extended from both ends. That would seem to be the most user-friendly solution. In fact, I don't know why that isn't the default behaviour, since it seems the most useful (and intuitive).